# Click eventListner is calling my function but only if I pass it anonymous function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a click eventListener who's calling a static method "clearCanv" but
one method inside "clearCanv" is not being called

> this.ctx.clearRect(x,y,this.canv.width, this.canv.width)

"clearCanv" is being called but that method is not being called.

**However if I pass the click evenetListner an anonymous function and I call my static method "clearCanv" from within anonymous function all the sudden it works.**

Could someone explain why that is happening?

The problem is in the last couple lines in JS.
I'm using Firefox

```js
class Board {
  static initalize() {
    // Create Canvas
    this.canv = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canv.getContext("2d");

    this.canv.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    document.body.appendChild(this.canv);

    this.prevX, this.prevY;
    this.lineWidth = 25;
    this.color = "white"; //Default color
    this.prevColor = this.color;
    this.erase = false;
    // Bindings
    this.draw = Board.draw.bind(this);
    this.clearCanv = Board.clearCanv.bind(this);
  }


  static draw({
    x,
    y
  }) {
    // Draw a cericle on X, Y
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, this.lineWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();

    // If we have prevX/Y draw a line from prevX/Y
    // To currentX/Y
    if (this.prevX && this.prevY) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.moveTo(this.prevX, this.prevY);
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
      this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
      this.ctx.stroke();
      this.ctx.closePath();
    }
    // Recored X/Y
    this.prevX = x;
    this.prevY = y;
  }
  static clearCanv(x = 0, y = 0) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(x, y, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
  }
}

Board.initalize();

Board.canv.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  this.addEventListener("mousemove", Board.draw);
});

Board.canv.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  Board.prevX = null;
  Board.prevY = null;
  Board.canv.removeEventListener("mousemove", Board.draw);
});


const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");
//This does not work
clearBtn.addEventListener("click", Board.clearCanv);

// This works for some reson
//clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
//  Board.clearCanv();
//});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#clear {
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 222; */
}

#erase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5rem;
}

.erase-selected {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#mouseColor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11.2rem;
}

.font-size-select {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15.5rem;
}

.bg-color {
  position: absolute;
  left: 19.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="clear">Clear</button><button id="erase">erase</button><input type="color" id="mouseColor" />
<select class="font-size-select" id="select-size">
  <option selected value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
<select class="bg-color" id="select-bg">
  <option selected value="black">Dark</option>
  <option value="white">Light</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _"a **static** method"_ ... _"`this.ctx...`"_  do you see the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you face here is that `x=0, y=0` params of your `clearCanv` method are overridden by the ones passed by the event listener i.e `x= Event`.
*clearRect()* silently ignores the call because `x` is `NaN` for what it is concerned.

Simply removing the params here will fix the issue, since I guess you don't want it to be anything else than `0`.

```js
class Board {
  static initalize() {
    // Create Canvas
    this.canv = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canv.getContext("2d");

    this.canv.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    document.body.appendChild(this.canv);

    this.prevX, this.prevY;
    this.lineWidth = 25;
    this.color = "white"; //Default color
    this.prevColor = this.color;
    this.erase = false;
    // Bindings
    this.draw = Board.draw.bind(this);
    this.clearCanv = Board.clearCanv.bind(this);
  }


  static draw({
    x,
    y
  }) {
    // Draw a cericle on X, Y
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, this.lineWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();

    // If we have prevX/Y draw a line from prevX/Y
    // To currentX/Y
    if (this.prevX && this.prevY) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.moveTo(this.prevX, this.prevY);
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
      this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
      this.ctx.stroke();
      this.ctx.closePath();
    }
    // Recored X/Y
    this.prevX = x;
    this.prevY = y;
  }
// here remove the params  
//  static clearCanv(x = 0, y = 0) {
  static clearCanv() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
  }
}

Board.initalize();

Board.canv.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  this.addEventListener("mousemove", Board.draw);
});

Board.canv.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  Board.prevX = null;
  Board.prevY = null;
  Board.canv.removeEventListener("mousemove", Board.draw);
});


const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", Board.clearCanv);

// This worked because here the params were not overridden
//clearBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
//  Board.clearCanv();
//});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#clear {
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 222; */
}

#erase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5rem;
}

.erase-selected {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#mouseColor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11.2rem;
}

.font-size-select {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15.5rem;
}

.bg-color {
  position: absolute;
  left: 19.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="clear">Clear</button><button id="erase">erase</button><input type="color" id="mouseColor" />
<select class="font-size-select" id="select-size">
  <option selected value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
<select class="bg-color" id="select-bg">
  <option selected value="black">Dark</option>
  <option value="white">Light</option>
</select>
```

---

---

Now, it is really hard to let you continue on this path. You are completely misusing the language here.

You are using this *class* as if it were an instance. Instead remove all these `static`, create a real *class* and then make a new instance of this *class*.

```js
class Board {
  constructor() {
    // Create Canvas
    this.canv = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.ctx = this.canv.getContext("2d");

    this.canv.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canv.width = window.innerWidth;
    document.body.appendChild(this.canv);

    this.prevX, this.prevY;
    this.lineWidth = 25;
    this.color = "white"; //Default color
    this.prevColor = this.color;
    this.erase = false;
    // Bindings
    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
    this.clearCanv = this.clearCanv.bind(this);

  }


  draw({x,y}) {
    // Draw a circle on X, Y
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, this.lineWidth / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();

    // If we have prevX/Y draw a line from prevX/Y
    // To currentX/Y
    if (this.prevX && this.prevY) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.moveTo(this.prevX, this.prevY);
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
      this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
      this.ctx.stroke();
      this.ctx.closePath();
    }
    // Recored X/Y
    this.prevX = x;
    this.prevY = y;
  }
  clearCanv() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canv.width, this.canv.height);
  }
}

// create an instance of Board
const board = new Board();

board.canv.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  this.addEventListener("mousemove", board.draw);
});

board.canv.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  board.prevX = null;
  board.prevY = null;
  board.canv.removeEventListener("mousemove", board.draw);
});


const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", board.clearCanv);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#clear {
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 222; */
}

#erase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5rem;
}

.erase-selected {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5.5rem;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#mouseColor {
  position: absolute;
  left: 11.2rem;
}

.font-size-select {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15.5rem;
}

.bg-color {
  position: absolute;
  left: 19.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="clear">Clear</button><button id="erase">erase</button><input type="color" id="mouseColor" />
<select class="font-size-select" id="select-size">
  <option selected value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
</select>
<select class="bg-color" id="select-bg">
  <option selected value="black">Dark</option>
  <option value="white">Light</option>
</select>
```